# Python Workflow like RStudio?

Tags: python, vim, workflow, ipython

I use Python as my main programming language, sometimes switching to R for quick data-analysis tasks due to it’s huge library for statistical programming purposes (although [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for python is great!). I guess that most R-Users go for [R-Studio](http://www.rstudio.com/), which is like an IDE for R. There are probably hundreds of IDE’s for Python, but i’d like to stick with VIM and IPython. Although there is the [vim-ipython](https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython)-plugin, i can’t recreate the R-Studio workflow, which is mainly:

1. Write code in the source-editor
2. "push" or execute it within the console window via CTRL-Enter
3. after that, the results get displayed in the console window or the plotting window

When using the vim-ipython plugin, you can execute vim-lines via CTRL-S, but the results in the running IPython-Kernel/QTconsole are not updating. Instead, the output goes directly to a VIM window (`<leader>s` opens it, but the window closes all the time and isn´t able to display inline-graphics, like the ipython-qtconsole does).

I’m sure this isn’t a new "problem", but is there any setup for VIM and (I)Python, which mimics the RStudio behavior and integrates both the editor and the interactive interpreter like modern IDE’s do? Copying text from vim to the interactive interpreter can’t be the optimal solution, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way of doing this in vim is to run vim inside a [gnu-screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) session with the REPL in a second screen in the session.  You can then use [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime) to send code from vim to the REPL.